# ASP.NET C# Code button in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

Hi all I have a GridView (GridView1) I have added a column and insert a button:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="798px">
            <Columns>
                .....
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="cmdFlag" Text="Flag" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Basically on click of the button I want to run a SQL Update but cant seem to click the button to enter C# and add the query. I can get in the C# for the page but unsure what to write for the method.

Heres the C# Code:

```
 void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "cmdFlag")
        {
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Comments SET Flagged = '" + "Yes" + "'", con); 

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }

    }
```

Its doing nothing though. Basically I need it to look at the row and if the flagged button is clicked, update the comment to "Yes" under flagged.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get a direct event. You need to write code on the RowCommand event.

```
void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName=="cmdFlag")
        {
        //Write code update database
    }
}
```

Also you need to modify the GridView control. Add event like this.

```
onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
```

You can get more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.aspx)

Comment: Hiya Thanks for that I have added it but its not doing what I want. Can you look at my post again I have updated it with more info.

Comment: Thanks mate it now does something but updates all the rows I think I need a WHERE statement just not to sure how to write it in terms of where that row only any ideas? I have a field for Comment_ID if that helps.

Comment: You need to get the value by Row.Cells[] or you can do a find control.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add `OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"` on your Gridview, that's why it is not firing the RowCommand Event.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="798px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the event-handler in your code-behind file by doing this

```
GridView1.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(GridView1_RowCommand);
```

and add this in you aspx page

```
OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the ID to use it in your `WHERE` statement you can put it into `CommandArgument` like

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="cmdFlag" Text="Flag" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Comment_ID") %>' />
```

then in the code you can get it from

```
var id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
```

Update: just updated the code

Comment: Hiya I added the code you put but I get the error: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: try to replace CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Comment_ID") %>' with CommandArgument="Comment_ID"